# flash cs5.5 as3 - get unicode character of Arabic Presentation forms A and B

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, unicode

I have a string like 'دبي' and i want to get its correct unicode character. Currently, I am using str.charCodeAt(index) to get its unicode character but for Arabic characters it gives between 0600 and 06FF. However, i want Arabic Presentation Forms A and B - whichever is actually written.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The string you posted consists of three normal Arabic letters in the 0600...06FF range, so what you are getting *is* the correct Unicode characters. If you mean that you would like to determine the contextual glyph forms used, then that’s outside the character level and cannot be determined from the string. (It can be determined, by applying rules of Arabic writing, which forms *should* be used, but that’s different from knowing which forms *are* actually used by the rendering software.)

Arabic Presentation Forms are legacy characters not meant for normal use. Normal rendering is not supposed to convert normal character to such forms but to select glyphs contextually.

Comment: Thanks Jukka. I hope to find some other way. Regards